# Sphinx throws an exception on Python 3.4/Windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have successfully installed the sphnix on Windows/Python 3.4, then successfully generated a basic structure by calling `sphinx-quickstart`.

But when calling `sphinx-build html` or `make html`, it throws an exception:

```
D:\my-doc>make html
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\sphinx-build.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\__init__.py", line 51, in main sys.exit(build_main(argv))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\__init__.py", line 61, in build_main from sphinx import cmdline
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmdline.py", line 23, in <module> from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 37, in <module> from sphinx.builders import BUILTIN_BUILDERS
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\builders\__init__.py", line 23, in <module> from sphinx.util import i18n, path_stabilize
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\i18n.py", line 15, in <module> from babel.messages.pofile import read_po
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\__init__.py", line 12, in <module> from babel.messages.catalog import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\catalog.py", line 23, in <module> from babel.dates import format_datetime
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\dates.py", line 28, in <module> from babel.util import UTC, LOCALTZ
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\util.py", line 278, in <module> from babel import localtime
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 21, in <module> from babel.localtime._win32 import _get_localzone
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 18, in <module> tz_names = get_global('windows_zone_mapping')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\core.py", line 58, in get_global _global_data = pickle.load(fileobj) TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I guess this is about compatibilities, since I have followed the tutorial step by step. Also been googling for this issue for hours and could not find an answer so far. Is it something I'm doing wrong or is it a compatibility issue?

Comment: Is there anything in the `conf.py` (or other configuration file) that is a time-zone, but is given as a string? (Seen the last lines of the traceback). E.g., using `'2'` instead of `2`.

Comment: You're not alone: I'm experiencing the same bug on Python 3.4/Windows. Looking into the issue now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug appears to be in babel v2.0. I downgraded to 1.3 (`pip install babel==1.3`) and the issue went away. Let me know if this works for you.